# onmousemove event occurring twice

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a custom video player using javascript, the code should display the overlay on onmousemove event it does trigger the code but for some reason twice, I think it is happening because of double full screen div's on top of each other but I cannot figure out the exact reason.

the HTML code for it is as follows

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Video Player</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"</script>
<style>
    video { object-fit: fill; }

    #video-player {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        z-index: -1;
    }
    #overlay
    {
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        position:fixed;
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        display: none;
    }
    #toggle
    {
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body style="cursor: none">
    <video id="video-player" width="100%" height="100%" controls>
    <source src="/Users/Himanshu/Downloads/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    <div id="overlay">
        <button id="toggle">play</button>
    </div>
    <script src="mediaPlayer.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and the Javascript code is as follows

```
var videoPlayer=document.getElementById("video-player");
var toggleButton=document.getElementById("toggle");
videoPlayer.controls=false;
toggleButton.addEventListener("click",function(){
if(videoPlayer.paused)
    {
        toggleButton.innerHTML="pause";
        videoPlayer.play();
    }
else
    {
        toggleButton.innerHTML="play";
        videoPlayer.pause();
    }
});
videoPlayer.onended=function(){
toggleButton.innerHTML="play";
};
var isHidden=true;
window.onmousemove=function(){
    if(isHidden)
    {
        console.log("Mouse Move Registered right now");
        isHidden=false;
        document.body.style.cursor="default";
        document.getElementById("overlay").style.display="inline";
        setTimeout(hide,1000);
    }
};
var hide=function(){
    console.log("here");
    document.getElementById("overlay").style.display="none";
    document.body.style.cursor="none";
    isHidden=true;
};
```

also how do I hide the cursor.

Comment: If you want to hide a cursor (to do it, wrap all content with `div`-`cursor: none`, don't use `body`), how could the user reach play/pause control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How often a mousemove or resize event is triggered depends largely on the browser implementation. Sometimes a function is repeatedly called to fast.  This is why many libraries use “debouncing” functions in such cases.

I suggest you to read David Walsh's article on [JavaScript Debounce Functions](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function). It also contains an example function (from Underscore.js).

```
// Returns a function, that, as long as it continues to be invoked, will not
// be triggered. The function will be called after it stops being called for
// N milliseconds. If `immediate` is passed, trigger the function on the
// leading edge, instead of the trailing.
function debounce(func, wait, immediate)
```

The `immediate` flag of that function causes the given event handler to be called once, in the moment the event is triggered the first time, but not again, until that event is not triggered anymore for `wait` milliseconds.

Comment: I solved the problem by waiting for 500 milliseconds after the overlay disappears,thanks for the reference though it is really interesting.